# Shell Script: Want to delete two consecutive lines matching pattern from specific line

Tags: text-processing, command-line, sed

I want to delete specific two consecutive lines matching patterns from specific line from a file.

For e.g. file contents are like below.

```
Line1: a
Line2: b
Line3: c
Line4: Name: 123
Line5:  xyz
Line6: Name: 456
Line7:  abc
```

I want to find the lines starting from line 4, matching 1st line pattern starting with "Name: " and matching 2nd line pattern starting with whitespace and delete the two consecutive lines.

Any efficient way to do this in shell using `sed` or something else?

To be a bit more clear, I want to remove signing/checksum information from the MANIFEST.MF.

Sample MANIFEST.MF like below:
From the below manifest file, I want to remove the entry "Name: ". where "Name: " entry can be in one line or 2(or more) lines.

Initially my solution was like find the first "Name: " entry followed by "SHA-256-Digest: " entry and delete to the end of the file. Unfortunately this solution has a problem of removing one needed entry in the middle. For e.g. "NetBeans-Simply-Convertible: " is also being removed.

So, now I want to remove "Name: " entry if available in 1 line or entry spanned across 2 or more lines. But I should not lose entries like "NetBeans-Simply-Convertible: " while removing "Name: " entries.

Already I am removing "SHA-256-Digest: " entries with the below command on file with `sed -i "/^\SHA-256-Digest: /d" $manifest_file`

---

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Version-Info: ....

Name: com/abc/xyz/pqr/client/relationship/message/notifier/Relati
 onshipUpdateNotifierFactory.class
SHA-256-Digest: cSSyk6Y2L2F9N6FPtswUkxjF2kelMkGe4bFprcQ+3uY=

Name: com/abc/xyz/pqr/client/relationship/ui/BaseRelationshipView
 $5.class
SHA-256-Digest: w9HgRjDuP024U4CyxeKPYFe6rzuzxZF3b+9LVG36XP8=

Name: com/abc/xyz/pqr/client/impl/MofRelationshipAgentImpl.class
SHA-256-Digest: GwIBIU+UdPtjyRhayAVM90Eo+SwCT/kP65dI59adEnM=

Name: com/abc/xyz/pqr/client/settings/ConvertibleProperties.class
NetBeans-Simply-Convertible: {com/abc/xyz/pqr/client/settings}Con
 vertibleProperties
SHA-256-Digest: 5FszAtfpPXcLx/6FBWbfeg6E4fwFMRozV+Q+3rReATc= ...
```

Expected Output:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Version-Info: ....


NetBeans-Simply-Convertible: {com/abc/xyz/pqr/client/settings}Con
 vertibleProperties

...
```

Comment: So you want to delete a line that matches a pattern and the next line after it?

Comment: what is the expected output... will line 6 and 7 be deleted as well? and add sample input where it doesn't match and should not be deleted

Comment: Hi Stephen,Sundeep, I elaborated a bit more about the problem. Please check. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

***awk*** approach:

Let's say we have the following input file `file.txt`(considering that each line contains `Line<number>:` as first field):

```
Line1: a
Line2: b
Line3: c
Line4: Name: 123
Line5:  xyz
Line6: Name: 456
Line7:  abc
Line8: Name: 111
Line9: www
Line10: Num: 222
Line11:  abc
Line12: Name: 333
Line13:  ccc
```

---

```
awk '{ if ($2 == "Name:") { 
           if ((getline l) > 0){ 
               if (l ~ /^\S+  \S+/) { next } else { print $0 RS l }               
           }
       } else { print } 
}' file.txt
```

The output:

```
Line1: a
Line2: b
Line3: c
Line8: Name: 111
Line9: www
Line10: Num: 222
Line11:  abc
```

---

***‘getline var’*** - reads the next record from awk's input into the variable `var`

> The *getline* command returns 1 if it finds a record and 0 if it
>   encounters the end of the file.

Comment: Hi Roman, I elaborated the problem bit more. Please check once. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You see that what you are asking is not clear: one answer deletes 4 lines (the two matching and the two subsequent ones); another deletes everything *but* the matching lines...

I'll throw in what I understand you want: I delete 2 lines, the one matching `Name: 123` and the subsequent one. I do this with `sed`:

```
sed -e '/Name: 123/{N;d}' filename
```

Comment: Hi Dario, I elaborated the problem bit more. Please check once. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Using `ed`:

```bash
$ printf '%s\n' 'g/^ / s///\' '-,.j' 'g/^Name: /d' 'g/SHA-256-Digest: /d' '4,$g/^$/d' ,p Q | ed -s file
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Version-Info: ....

NetBeans-Simply-Convertible: {com/abc/xyz/pqr/client/settings}ConvertibleProperties
```

This applies the following edit script to you input file:

```
g/^ / s///\
-,.j
g/^Name: /d
g/SHA-256-Digest: /d
4,$g/^$/d
,p
Q
```

This consists of six separate commands:

1. The two commands `s///` and `-,. j` applied to every line that starts with a space character.  The empty regular expression in the `s` command re-uses the expression `^`  from the preceding `g` command (which is used for applying one or more commands to lines matching a regular expression), so the `s` command removes the first empty space on lines that start with empty spaces.  The `j` command then joins the modified line with the previous line.  This effectively undoes the wrapping of the lines in the input data.
2. The command `d` is applied to all lines that start with `Name:` , removing these.
3. Similarly, lines starting with `SHA-256-Digest:`  are removed.
4. Empty lines are removed from line 4 onwards.
5. We output the complete buffer to standard output to display the result.
6. `Q` quits the editor unconditionally (you could use `wq` to write the changes back to the original file).

Answer (score -1):

```
sed -e '
   4,$!d;      # skip non-relevant portion
   /Name:/N;   # grab the line coming after Name:
   /\n.* /d;   # what we were after is not this
   P;D
' yourfile
```

Comment: Hi Rakesh, I elaborated the problem bit more. Please check once. Thanks.

Comment: HI Rakesh, 4, $!d is deleting the lines from 1 line to 4th line. What I want is, I want to keep the 1st three lines untouched, means I don't want to delete. I wan sed command to act from 4th line. Thanks

Comment: This appears to produce garbage I afraid.